# Show content in GridView footer in the Page_Load event method

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am getting Application name from querystring.

I have GridView control that I can use to insert some Tasks. I have to insert Tasks based on the Application name I am getting in the querystring. I am inserting Record in the GridView footer. Since, application name is coming from Querystring, I want to show it as one item in the GridView footer. How can I do this while Page_Loading time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind to the RowDataBound event and then check the event to see if it is the footer like so:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = Request["ApplicationName"];
            }
        }
```